# Select box "Other" option in dropdown label

Tags: forms, dropdown, selection, select

For dropdown options that have an "Other" option that will then display an textbox, what typically is the label for this textbox? Should the label be `Other`?

Comment: The textbox might just be next to the dropdown, using the dropdown and the dropdown's label as its label.

Comment: As well as location, it could be disabled/hidden when not needed so that when it is enabled/revealed the user knows what it related to. Sometimes they have placeholder text "Other..." to make it more obvious.

Comment: Is there any reason that "Other" wouldn't be a suitable label? What are some of the options in the list?